# how to join a select statement with the union of two other select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, union

**table_a:**

| id | description | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "blah blah" | Category 1 |
| 1 | "lots of words" | Category 1 |
| 2 | "helpful description" | Category 1 |
| 3 | "very pleased" | Category 1 |
| 4 | "5 stars" | Category 1 |
| 5 | "pretty good" | Category 1 |
| 6 | "not great" | Category 1 |
| 7 | "good work" | Category 1 |
| 8 | "not impressed" | Category 2 |
| 9 | "just okay" | Category 2 |

**table_b:**

| id | num | person_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 000 | 00000000 | b |
| 1 | 100 | 11111111 | b |
| 2 | 200 | 22222222 | b |
| 3 | 300 | 33333333 | b |

**table_c:**

| id | num | person_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 400 | 44444444 | c |
| 5 | 500 | 55555555 | c |
| 6 | 600 | 66666666 | c |
| 7 | 700 | 77777777 | c |

**Desired:**

| id | num | person_id | type | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 000 | 00000000 | b | "blah blah" |
| 1 | 100 | 11111111 | b | "lots of words" |
| 2 | 200 | 22222222 | b | "helpful description" |
| 3 | 300 | 33333333 | b | "very pleased" |
| 4 | 400 | 44444444 | c | "5 stars" |
| 5 | 500 | 55555555 | c | "pretty good" |
| 6 | 600 | 66666666 | c | "not great" |
| 7 | 700 | 77777777 | c | "good work" |

The following gives me a "SQL command not properly ended" at the line with just `t1`. I know this error has to do with how I aliased that table but I'm not sure what to do next.

```
SELECT 
    id, description
FROM 
    table_a
WHERE category = 'Category 1'
t1

LEFT JOIN

(
SELECT 
    id, num, person_id, type
FROM 
    table_b
UNION
SELECT 
    id, num, person_id, type
FROM 
    table_c
) t2
ON 
    t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is a clause that follows the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you expect

```
SELECT   t1.id, t2.num, t2.person_id, t2.type, t2.description
FROM     table_a t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  id, num, person_id, type
    FROM    table_b
    UNION
    SELECT id, num, person_id, type
    from   table_c
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    
WHERE category = 'Category 1'
```

Comment: I think your first select statement doesnt have the proper columns, but either way i get "column ambiguously defined" at line 1

Comment: Yep, we have id in both tables so we need to say which one need to be selected. I updated the query

Comment: This worked well, but I think you forgot to add the column "num" in the first line

Comment: Sure, you can get all the columns you need. Most important is that you've got the idea

Answer (score 1):

Two options either use the where clause in a subquery or use it after the join condition.

```
SELECT 
    id, description
FROM 
    table_a
t1

LEFT JOIN

(
SELECT 
    id, num, person_id, type
FROM 
    table_b
UNION
SELECT 
    id, num, person_id, type
FROM 
    table_c
) t2
ON 
    t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.category = 'Category 1'
```

or

```
select * from (SELECT 
    id, description
FROM 
    table_a WHERE category = 'Category 1')
t1

LEFT JOIN

(
SELECT 
    id, num, person_id, type
FROM 
    table_b
UNION
SELECT 
    id, num, person_id, type
FROM 
    table_c
) t2
ON 
    t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.category = 'Category 1'
```